# Best way to update several values in hashmap?

Tags: clojure

I have a hash map like this:

```
{:key1 "aaa bbb ccc" :key2 "ddd eee" :key3 "fff ggg" :do-not-split "abcdefg hijk"}
```

And I'd like to split some of the strings to get vectors:

```
; expected result
{:key1 ["aaa" "bbb" "ccc"] :key2 ["ddd" "eee"] :key3 ["fff" "ggg"] :do-not-split "abcdefg hijk"}
```

I use `update-in` three times now like the following but it seems ugly.

```
(-> my-hash (update-in [:key1] #(split % #"\s")) 
            (update-in [:key2] #(split % #"\s")) 
            (update-in [:key3] #(split % #"\s")))
```

I hope there's sth like `(update-all my-hash [:key1 :key2 :key3] fn)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/reduce):

```
user=> (def my-hash {:key1 "aaa bbb ccc" :key2 "ddd eee" :key3 "fff ggg"})
#'user/my-hash
user=> (defn split-it [s] (clojure.string/split s #"\s"))
#'user/split-it
user=> (reduce #(update-in %1 [%2] split-it) my-hash [:key1 :key2 :key3])
{:key3 ["fff" "ggg"], :key2 ["ddd" "eee"], :key1 ["aaa" "bbb" "ccc"]}
```

Comment: `[:key1 :key2 :key3]` probably replace with `(keys my-hash)`

Comment: @mishadoff I think it's the intention of the OP that he can specify which keys to replace, and not simply all. Otherwise, you could simply use one function of the map-family instead of reduce.

Comment: `reduce` seems the best choice. Since I always had a bad mindset that `reduce` is used to accumulate something together, I forgot this way. Thank u very much.

Comment: Honestly, reduce does not seem like a natural way to transform the elements of an associative collection. That's what map is for.

Answer (score 2):

Just map the values based on a function that makes the decision about whether to split or not.

```
user=> (def x {:key1 "aaa bbb ccc" 
               :key2 "ddd eee" 
               :key3 "fff ggg" 
               :do-not-split "abcdefg hijk"})
#'user/x

user=> (defn split-some [predicate [key value]] 
         (if (predicate key) 
           [key (str/split value #" ")] 
           [key value]))
#'user/split-some

user=> (into {} (map #(split-some #{:key1 :key2 :key3} %) x))
{:do-not-split "abcdefg hijk", :key3 ["fff" "ggg"], :key2 ["ddd" "eee"], :key1 ["aaa" "bbb" "ccc"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a different way of approaching the problem.

Think about it for a second: if your string were in a list, how would you approach it?

The answer is that you would use `map` to get a list of vectors:

```
(map #(split % #"\s") list-of-strings)
```

If you think harder you would arrive at the conclusion that what you really want is to **map** a function over the **values** of a map. Obviously `map` doesn't work here as it works for sequences only.

However, is there a generic version of map? It turns out there is! It's called `fmap` and comes from the concept of *functors* which you can ignore for now. This is how you would use it:

```
(fmap my-hash #(split % #"\s"))
```

See how the intent is a lot clearer now?

The only drawback is that fmap isn't a core function but it is available through the [algo.generic](https://github.com/clojure/algo.generic) library.

Of course if including a new library feels like too much at this stage, you can always steel the source code - and attribute to its author - from the library itself in [this link](https://github.com/clojure/algo.generic/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/algo/generic/functor.clj):

```
(into (empty my-hash) (for [[k v] my-hash] [k (your-function-here v)]))
```

Comment: Interesting. I've thought of `fmap` earlier, but It seems I only need to change some values, which are in the minority in the hashmap.

Comment: That should be fine. Your function would have a predicate that checks whether the value should be updated and if not, just return the original.